# Is the RE and the finite automata same?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory

[image]

I want to understand if RE a∗ba∗ab∗  is same as the following the finite automata. The Part where I am confused is that, From state 3 to state 4 , there is a b , which means that the language needs to have a b at the end , while the RE just has b* which means 0 or more b . If not what is correct finite automata for this RE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the regular expression `a*ba*ab*` is not equivalent to the DFA shown for exactly the reason you stated in your question.

[Thompson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) is a standard way of systematically converting a regular expression into an NFA. (If you need the finite automaton to be deterministic, you can then run the [subset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).)